# Keeping track of the sum of each element of a vector to another vector

Tags: r, vector, sum

I have two vectors where I want to sum each element of a vector `a` to vector `b`. But I want to  also keep track of which element of `a` and `b` that will give me that value. I have tried the following to get my output:

```
a <- 1:3
b <- 4:6

store <- list()

for(i in 1:length(b)){
        for(j in 1:length(a)){
                total <- b[i] + a[j]
                store[[paste0("a",i, "+","b",j)]] <- total  
        }        
}

## output
> unlist(store)
## a1+b1 a1+b2 a1+b3 a2+b1 a2+b2 a2+b3 a3+b1 a3+b2 a3+b3 
## 5     6     7     6     7     8     7     8     9
```

But I find using nested `for` loops are inflexible as it won't work that well if the length of `a` and `b` are different.

I have came across the `outer()` function, where I can easily achieve the same result as above using one line of code:

```
c(outer(a,b,`+`))
##[1] 5 6 7 6 7 8 7 8 9
```

However, I lost track of the pair that will give me this value.

How can I track the pair without using loops?

Comment: You could try `nm <- outer(seq_along(a), seq_along(b), FUN = function(x, y) sprintf('a%d + b%d', x, y))` and set it at the names of the previous `outer` output

Comment: Perfect, many thanks akrun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a second `outer` to get the `names` and use that the assign the names of the first one

```
nm <- outer(seq_along(a), seq_along(b), FUN = function(x, y) sprintf('a%d + b%d', x, y))
res <- setNames(c(outer(a,b,`+`)), nm)
res 
#   a1 + b1 a2 + b1 a3 + b1 a1 + b2 a2 + b2 a3 + b2 a1 + b3 a2 + b3 a3 + b3 
#      5       6       7       6       7       8       7       8       9
```